# In erlang is it possible to have concurrent readers of data owned by another process?

Tags: erlang

My understanding of the message passing system is that it is serialized and therefore all the reads from different processes are serialized even if the data isn't changing.  I would like to have the data read concurrently if possible to take advantage of distributed computing.  Is this possible?

Comment: I had a rather long answer and then I realized I don't know what you mean at all. Perhaps you could reframe your question in a more concrete example so people could give some advice on how to increase parallel access.

Comment: I must agree here, I also don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in that messages will be handled sequentially in a process receiving them.

If the data really is static (well, even if it changes sometimes) consider using an [ETS table](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) for this kind of scenario. ETS tables are highly optimized for concurrent access whenever applicable. Unless someone is writing to an ETS table (or row) all clients can read the data concurrently from the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different processes on the same computer (IMO, this is not a **distributed** computing), binary type is not serialized, it is passed by reference. So you can read large block of data by many processes without actually copying it. The very idea of "data read concurrently" in a really distributed world doesn't seem right to me (ETS is not an exception).

P.S. Well, what I meant in the last statement was "it doesn't save you from serializing".

Comment: I'm interested to know why the reads need to be serial.  I'm new to Erlang and concurrent computing.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean when you say "reads need to be serial". What kind of reads?

Comment: In sequence instead of concurrent.

Comment: Xavier, I'm also not sure what you mean by "in sequence". If you don't have SMP enabled, then no matter what, only one process at a time can be literally doing anything at all. That is, in a single node. With multiple nodes, it's another story.

Comment: I took serial to mean that reads are performed in the order they are received.  However in a distributed system with multiple computers.  I would think some of those reads could be performed concurrently.

Comment: I'm sorry, and I know SO does not encourage extended discussions, but I still don't see what you mean. Each process reads *its own* messages in the order they are received. But in a distributed system, of course many processes in many nodes can be each reading *its own* processes at once.

Comment: Let me elaborate a little. It sounds like your understanding is that there's a single global message inbox from which all processes may read, but only one process may read at a time. This is not correct. Each process has its own mailbox, and reads may be concurrent.

Comment: "reads" or receiving messages from the process mailbox are always sequential, since it is the process that reads them and a process is just a sequential program. If you send 5 messages to 5 different processes, they can all read their mailbox concurrently.